# Functional way to handle JMSConnection open and close with Clojure

Tags: clojure, jms

I wrote this code to automatically open and close my `JMSConnection`'s in Clojure:

```
(defn with-jms
  ([provider-url context-factory factory-name fn args]
   (with-open [jndi-ctx (new InitialContext (populate-env provider-url context-factory))
               jms-conn (-> (.lookup jndi-ctx factory-name)
                            (.createConnection))]
       (apply fn (-> (sequence args)
                     (conj jms-conn)
                     (conj jndi-ctx)))))
  ([fn args]
   (let [{provider-url    "provider-url"
          context-factory "context-factory"
          factory-name    "factory-name"} jms-properties]
     (with-jms provider-url context-factory factory-name fn args))))
```

Note how properties are used for convenience. Please also note that `populate-env` is a function that returns a HashTable populated with the necessary JMS properties.

I can then define JMS functions the following way:

```
(defn send-text-message! [jndi-ctx jms-conn topic content]
  (with-open [session (.createSession jms-conn false Session/AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
              producer (.createProducer session (.lookup jndi-ctx topic))]
    (let [message (.createTextMessage session content)]
      (.send producer message))))
```

I can combine both functions in the following way :

```
(with-jms send-text-message! ["clojureTopic" "azerty"])
```

However I'm not 100% satisfied with it. These are the things that puzzle me:

- In `with-jms`, the `args` in `with-jms` is an array, because overloading and multi-varied arguments is not supported in Clojure. Is there a better alternative?
- In `with-jms`, the `(apply fn (-> (sequence args) (conj jms-conn) (conj jndi-ctx)))` part feels really clunky, is there a better way to write that?
- When I call `with-jms` function, I must remember to exclude the `jndi-ctx` and the `jms-conn` from the argument lists even if it's in the called function signature. I don't like it, I find it confusing. I tried to write a wrapper that returns a partial function but it felt unnecessary and tedious to do for every JMS function. Maybe there's a better way to write `with-jms`?

Any help would be appreciated !